# How do I find compiler and link options that were used to build NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I find out information on how NumPy was built. I can see some information with numpy.show_config(). But I want to know if, for example it was built with avx options.

Answer (score 1):

numpy.show_config() now shows whether AVX and other SIMD extensions are supported on the current build:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.show_config()
```

This is the output on Ubuntu 21.10 using Numpy 1.22.2:

```
...
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```

As you can see AVX512 extensions are not supported on my machine, but SSE and the base AVX is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the full configuration environment through NumPy distutils. For a Unix/Linux system.

```
import numpy.distutils
np_config_vars = numpy.distutils.unixccompiler.sysconfig.get_config_vars()

import pprint
pprint.pprint(np_config_vars)
```

This will give a lot of configuration information. You could grep through this to find what you are looking for. I don't think you wlll find AVX options coming as standard. You may wan't to create your own build.

The output produced from the above command is a dictionary so you could extract fields e.g:

```
print(np_config_vars['CFLAGS'])
```

Or for particular fields you can specify them as arguments  E.g:

```
compile_vars = numpy.distutils.unixccompiler.sysconfig.get_config_vars('CC', 'CFLAGS', 'LDSHARED')
```

Your compile link lines may be composed of several fields, however.

More information [here](https://shuds13.github.io/python-tutorials/tutorials/interrogating_numpy.html)

Comment: This does not seem to work in python3.10 using numpy1.22.2, in Ubuntu 21.10:

AttributeError: module 'numpy.distutils.unixccompiler' has no attribute 'sysconfig'